# For Each loop in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to loop through different data on the same view, sometimes the data looks like this:

```
[{"id":"3","title":"Collection C","short_title":"CC","looks":[{"id":"6","title":"Look 6","image":null,"sell":null,"description":null,"sort":null,"published":"1","pivot":{"collection_id":"3","look_id":"6"}},{"id":"7","title":"Look 7","image":null,"sell":null,"description":null,"sort":"1","published":"1","pivot":{"collection_id":"3","look_id":"7"}}]},{"id":"1","title":"Collection A","short_title":"CA","looks":[{"id":"2","title":"Look 2","image":null,"sell":null,"description":null,"sort":"0","published":"1","pivot":{"collection_id":"1","look_id":"2"}}]}]
```

And other times it looks like this:

```
{"id":"1","title":"Collection A","thumb":null,"banner":null,"video":"ftfgf","looks":[{"id":"2","title":"Look 2","image":null,"sell":null,"description":null,"sort":"0","published":"1","url":"test","pivot":{"collection_id":"1","look_id":"2"}}]} BESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswyBESbswy
```

I loop it out via:

```
@foreach($data as $show)
{{ $show->title }}
@endforeach
```

The second set of data breaks my loop, is this becuase it's not in an array itself, if so, how can I put it into an array so it's the only element.

Or is there a better way to tackle the problem?

Comment: Your controller should always make sure that the data is an array, and not a single entry.

Comment: The difference between ->get() and ->first()

Comment: @Thomas Ruiz no it shouldnt

Comment: @panthro it should - your view should be able to rely on certain things being constant. If you get different things back from a given source, your controller should normalise it for your view. In general, the idea is that views should contain as little logic as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you are using an object not an array.

One thing you should ask yourself is why do you end up in a situation where `$data` can be an object or an array?

In my view you should be more robust with your code. If you know you are doing a `foreach` on `$data`, you should enforce that it is always an array, otherwise you are going to get in a right mess.

If you cant change the source, you could do something like this before your foreach

```
<?php if(!is_array($data)) $data[] = $data; ?>
```

Or, as you stated, you should use `->toArray()` on your models before outputting

You could (i think) also use `->get()` rather than `->first()` on your eloquent query. I think `->get()` always outputs an array.

So long as you can be sure that `$data` is always and array, you should be ok.

**Update Based on your comment:**

Do this to ensure you output as an array

```
$data = $this->with(array('looks' => function($query){ $query->wherePublished(1)->orderBy('sort')->take(3)->skip(0); }))->get($id, array('id', 'title', 'thumb', 'banner', 'video'));  

if(is_array($data))
{
  return $data;
}

return array($data);
```

Comment: I take it you have never used laravel?

Comment: I would tend to agree that making sure you have consistent data going to your view is probably the best approach.  I think @panthro's confusion is the lack of blade formatting with your if.

Comment: So should I use ->toArray() in my models then before passing to my views?

Comment: return $this->with(array('looks' => function($query){
            $query->wherePublished(1)->orderBy('sort')->take(3)->skip(0);
        }))->find($id, array('id', 'title', 'thumb', 'banner', 'video'))->toArray();

Comment: ah, you are using find(). It always produces an object.

Comment: I get the error: Array to string conversion when trying to convert to array

Comment: do this $data = $this->with(array('looks' => function($query){ $query->wherePublished(1)->orderBy('sort')->take(3)->skip(0); }))->find($id, array('id', 'title', 'thumb', 'banner', 'video'));  return array($data);

Comment: To array works but it's my view causing the issues, im trying to get the data out with {{ $data }} not working now it's an array?

Comment: {{ $data }} is never going to work. Its not a string, or anything that can be cast to a string. What are you actually trying  to achieve by echoing out $data?

Comment: What can I use to output the data then?

Comment: then do this {{ $data[0] }}

Comment: ErrorException' with message 'Undefined offset: 0'

Comment: Whats the point of putting it in an array just to json encode it again?

Comment: I really dont get this. Why bither putting it in to an array, why not pass teh object through to the view so it can then be accessed via {{ $data->title }}

Comment: Well you can do that, but look at your question - you were telling us you sometimes had an array, and sometimes had an object. If you are using find() you will only every have an object, so you dont even need the foreach

Comment: Both times it's an object, an eloquent object

Comment: [{"id":"3"...] = array ...  {"id":"3"...} = object

Comment: so get() returns an array and find() returns an onbject (in eloquent)

Comment: YES!! You got it! :-)  first() also produces an object

Comment: finally, thanks for your endless help, i'll try and work this out

Comment: Ive just checked and get also does return an object: object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#212 (1)

Comment: return $this->with(array('looks' => function($query){
            $query->wherePublished(1)->orderBy('sort')->take(3)->skip(0);
        }))->whereInCollection(1)->wherePublished(1)->orderBy('date')->take(3)->skip(0)->get(array('id', 'title', 'short_title'));

Comment: the simple fact of the matter is you need to check the output before sending to a view. It should always be an array. To do this, get the data from eloquent and save to $data. Run a check on $data to see if its an array, if it is, great! send to view. If its not, make it an array $data = array($data) then send to view. Then in your view you MUST use a foreach. foreach($data as $model) {{$model->title }}

Comment: How come this is not shown in any of the examples then? It says nothing about converting eloquent to an aray before sending toa  view

Comment: foreach($data as $model) {{$model->title }} this also fails: 'ErrorException' with message 'Undefined variable: model'

Comment: why would it? You as a developer should manage that - they are your views

Answer (score 0):

I'd do some checks before you start looping to see if it's the first type of data or the second.

```
@if (is_array($data))
    @foreach($data as $show)
    {{ $show->title }}
    @endforeach
@else
    {{-handle it as an object-}}
@endif
```

Comment: It always returns 'else' with my arrays